# How to run kinit as root before automounting mutiuser cifs mounts?

Tags: kerberos, cifs, fstab, ntlm, kinit

## Goal

I'm setting up multi-user CIFS mounts in an Active Directory environment under CentOS 8.2. The storage server supports SMB3.1.1 protocol.

### Prerequisites

I could easily integrate the system to the Active Directory and I've edited SSSD (/etc/sssd/sssd.conf) and `realm` configuration to match preferences and needs.

Results:

- Active Directory users can login

I've also created a dedicated user that I'll name in this post "*mountorino*". *mountorino* has required share permissions (RO) and NTFS permissions (traverse root folder) to mount the CIFS shares. Identification information is stored in the `/root/cifs.cred` file.

### Scenario A: NTLM

Mounting the CIFS shares with the `multiuser` and `ntlmsspi` options:

`//<server>/<share>  /mnt/<mount point>    cifs    auto,_netdev,rw,noexec,nodev,nosuid,noperm,cache=strict,hard,vers=3.1.1,multiuser,sec=ntlmsspi,credentials=/root/cifs.cred        0 0`

Results:

- It works as long as, from the end-user context,  I run the `cifscreds add --username <user> <server>` command
- It doesn't work if I run `cifscreds add --username <user> --domain <domain>` command

### Scenario B: Kerberos

Mounting the CIFS shares with the `multiuser`, `krb5i`, and `cruid` options:

`//<server>/<share>  /mnt/<mount point>    cifs    auto,_netdev,rw,noexec,nodev,nosuid,noperm,cache=strict,hard,vers=3.1.1,multiuser,sec=krb5i,cruid=0,credentials=/root/cifs.cred        0 0`

Results:

- It works as long as, as root,  I run the `kinit mounterino@<DOMAIN>` command

## Questions:

- With NTLM, why `cifscreds add --username <user> --domain <domain>` doesn't work? The user, the server and the client all are members of the same Windows domain!
- More importantly, with Kerberos, how can I make root to get a Kerberos ticket *before* automounting fstab entries happens? I understand that by generating a `keytab` file, I won't have to type *moutorino* password when running `kinit`, which allows to automate `kinit` usage. But how do I make sure `kinit` is run before automounts are mounted? PAM? systemd unit?

## Sources

- https://computingforgeeks.com/join-centos-rhel-system-to-active-directory-domain/
- https://access.redhat.com/articles/3023821
- https://superuser.com/questions/1498295/how-can-i-write-to-dfs-share-with-different-users-other-than-mount-user-on-the-l
- [FSTAB CIFS kerberos](https://serverfault.com/questions/1002270/fstab-cifs-kerberos)

Best regards,
MauvaisJoueur

Comment: Why wouldn't you run a cronjob for ticket creation?. You could run it periodically or at system startup with "@reboot" keyword. Also, check out this : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12021/automatic-kerberos-ticket-initialization-on-login

Comment: Because I need this to happen in a very specific time frame: between network is up and systemd mounts fstab entries. I've check the link and I understand that it concerns Kerberos ticket creation for the user who logs in, which is not my case where no user logs in.

Comment: Ended up switching back to `ntlmsspi` and `cifscreds`.